# Creating a job system in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I want to create a job system in drupal 7 with the following workflow.

1. Administrator can add the jobs.
2. A for jobs listing.
3. On detail job there should a link of apply for this job.
4. The form will contain the fields and upload application form.
5. The back end must have trackers such as Response received at, action trackers: 'Candidate contacted, Candidate data transferred to HR', Vacany filled.

I have tried it with the views and the webform module.

Created a view for job listing. and use webform for apply form. But what should I do with the trackers in point 5. I have no idea about this.

Please guide me in this situation or any module for this requirement which should use?

Answer (score 2):

There are various distributions available in Drupal.org

You can check it out [Drupal jobs](http://drupal.org/project/drop_jobs) and [Recruiter](http://drupal.org/project/recruiter). both are well maintained.

Take these distributions as base and develop your project. They almost support all of your usecases.

Comment: I needs a small module not a distribution.

Comment: but you can see the modules/features from this site and use it

Comment: http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/build-job-listings-website-drupal-9134658